# Fullscreen QML application and background RPI touchscreen activity

Tags: c++, qt, qml, raspberry-pi3

I am working with QML on RPI. I have a problem with touchscreen. I am using Qt 5.9.1 and connecting RPI with VNC. When I debug my gui applications they are always working fullscreen on touchscreen and I can't see the app window on VNC. I am ok with only working fullscreen and not seeing on VNC but if I touch the screen it can reach behind the application window. I mean when application is active I can accidentally open desktop apps or change the desktop folders. I don't want to native-build Qt again because it takes so much time with rpi. How can my touchscreen work only on QML window?
Thanks for answers.
Here is main.cpp;

```
#include "ae2.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    Ae2 timer;
    QQmlContext* ctx=engine.rootContext();
    ctx->setContextProperty("benimHaberciReferansı",&timer);
    return app.exec();

}
```

main qml :

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Tesla Model S Speedometer")
    width: 800//1400
    height: 480//600
    visible: true
    color: "black"


       LeftElement {
                id: leftRect
                y: 50
                x: 0
                width: parent.width / 2
                height: 475
            }

       RightElement {
                id: rightRect
                y: 50
                x: 400
                width: parent.width / 2
                height: 475
            }


       QtObject {
           property var locale: Qt.locale()
           property date currentDate: new Date()
           property string dateString
           property string timeString

           Component.onCompleted: {
               dateString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString();
               timeString = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString();
           }
       }


       Image {
           width: parent.width
           height: parent.height
           source: "/pics/Background.png"
       }

    /*  Column {
           id: switch1
           y: 100
           x: 700
           Switch { checked: true }
           Text {
               text: "Mod1"
               font.pixelSize: 26
               font.bold: true
               color: "white"
           }
       }
       Column {
           id: switch2
           y: 200
           x: 700
           Switch { checked: true }
           Text {
               text: "Mod2"
               font.pixelSize: 26
               font.bold: true
               color: "white"
           }
       }*/
       //Leiste unten
    Rectangle {
    y: parent.height - 90
    height: 200
    width: parent.width
    color: "transparent"

            RowLayout {
                   y: 40
                   x: 170
                   Text {
                       text: "245"
                       font.pixelSize: 20
                       font.bold: true
                       color: "white"
                   }
                   Text {
                       text: "mi"
                       font.pixelSize: 20
                       font.bold: false
                       color: "darkgray"
                   }
               }

            RowLayout {
                   y: 40
                   x: 100
                   Text {
                       text: "69º"
                       font.pixelSize: 26
                       font.bold: true
                       color: "white"
                   }
                   Text {
                       text: "F"
                       font.pixelSize: 26
                       font.bold: false
                       color: "darkgray"
                   }
               }


            RowLayout {
                y: 40
                x: 600
                Text {
                    text: new Date().toLocaleDateString(Qt.locale(),"ddd") //ddd MMM d //h:mm AP
                    font.pixelSize: 20
                    font.bold: true
                    color: "white"
                }
                Text {
                    text: new Date().toLocaleDateString(Qt.locale(),"MMM d") //ddd MMM d //h:mm AP
                    font.pixelSize: 20
                    font.bold: false
                    color: "darkgray"
                }
            }

            RowLayout {
                y: 40
                x: 720
                Text {
                    text: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(Qt.locale(),"h:mm") //ddd MMM d //h:mm AP
                    font.pixelSize: 20
                    font.bold: false
                    color: "darkgray"
                }

            }
        }

//Tacho
    Image {
           height: parent.height
           width: height
           x: (parent.width / 2) - (width / 2)
           scale: 1.14
           source: "/pics/Tacho.png"
           fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }

    Speedometer {
       height: 525
       width: height
       x: (parent.width / 2) - (width / 2)
       y: (parent.height / 2) - (height / 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: By default it should work as you'd expect. So, you might have your hardware and OS setup incorrectly or have hit [one of the 8000+ open bugs in Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/issues). Try one of the [QML sample programs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-codesamples.html) shipped with Qt (the list is available in QtCreator for example).